# Rails Remote work with Callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a Ruby user. I'm trying to get a call back in a remote work in Ruby on rails to let an user get in the class room 15mins before the class. The reason I came down with remote work is, when the user keeps clicking the button ( unless if I don't reset the browser, the system seems not being able to calculate Time.now - start_time by changing Time.now value. So I decided to use a remote method to deal with this problem. ( But I'm open to a better idea! )

In the view,

```
<%= content_tag :div, class: "classenter" do %>
<%= button_to "class enter",  classenter_path, method: :get, remote: true, class:"btn ", params: { lesson_id: lesson.id, user_id: current_user.id} %>
<% end %>
```

*about classenter_path in routes.rb=>   `get :classenter, to: "application#class_enter"`

It goes to the application controller.

The controller looks like

```
def class_enter 

user = User.find_by(:id => params[:user_id])
    lesson = Lesson.find_by(:id => params[:lesson_id])

    ready = false
    if ((lesson.start_time - Time.now)/3600*60) < 15
     ready = true

    else
     ready = false
    end
end
```

After I compute whether it is ready or not, then I want to pass this information to the original view to whether let an user to get in the class room or not.

Also in the class_enter.js.erb file in /views/application, I want to put an alert to indicate users that the class is ready or not.

Pseudo code might look like

```
if ready == true
else
alert("not ready");
end
```

How can I get call back in this setting? I'm looking forward to hearing opinions from experts here!

Best